# trying to create a generic XSL to allow for slightly different XML formats

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, namespaces, transform

I am new to writing XSL transforms and I am trying to create an XSL that covers a certain format of XML I have two excamples here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Programme  xmlns="http://www.digitalproductionpartnership.co.uk/ns/as11/2012">
<Editorial xmlns="">
<SeriesTitle>Paul And Nicks Big American Food Trip Series 2</SeriesTitle>
<ProgrammeTitle>Paul And Nicks Big American Food Trip</ProgrammeTitle>
<EpisodeTitleNumber>Washington DC</EpisodeTitleNumber>
<ProductionNumber>PRG86396_1</ProductionNumber>
<Synopsis>Paul and Nick visit Washington DC to cook up an Ulster Scots meal for their guests.</Synopsis>
<Originator>Waddell Media</Originator>
<CopyrightYear>2015</CopyrightYear>
</Editorial>
<Technical xmlns="">
<ShimName>DPP V4.1 HD AVC-I AS-11</ShimName>
<Video>
  <PictureFormat>1080i50 16:9</PictureFormat>
  <AFD>10</AFD>
  <PictureRatio>16:9 (1.78:1)</PictureRatio>
  <ProductPlacement>false</ProductPlacement>
  <VideoComments>
  </VideoComments>
  <VideoBitRate unit="Mbps">100</VideoBitRate>
  <VideoCodecParameters>High 4:2:2 Intra@L4.1</VideoCodecParameters>
</Video>
<Audio>
  <PrimaryAudioLanguage>eng</PrimaryAudioLanguage>
  <SecondaryAudioLanguage>zxx</SecondaryAudioLanguage>
  <TertiaryAudioLanguage>zxx</TertiaryAudioLanguage>
  <AudioLoudnessStandard>_UKDPP_AUDIO_LOUDNESS_STANDARD_EBU_R_128</AudioLoudnessStandard>
  <AudioComments>
  </AudioComments>
</Audio>
<Timecodes>
  <LineUpStart>09:58:00:00</LineUpStart>
  <IdentClockStart>09:59:30:00</IdentClockStart>
  <Parts>
    <Part>
      <PartNumber>1</PartNumber>
      <PartTotal>3</PartTotal>
      <PartSOM>10:00:00:00</PartSOM>
      <PartDuration>00:10:46:00</PartDuration>
    </Part>
    <Part>
      <PartNumber>2</PartNumber>
      <PartTotal>3</PartTotal>
      <PartSOM>10:12:00:00</PartSOM>
      <PartDuration>00:11:34:00</PartDuration>
    </Part>
    <Part>
      <PartNumber>3</PartNumber>
      <PartTotal>3</PartTotal>
      <PartSOM>10:24:38:15</PartSOM>
      <PartDuration>00:00:20:20</PartDuration>
    </Part>
  </Parts>
  <TotalNumberOfParts>3</TotalNumberOfParts>
  <TotalProgrammeDuration>00:22:40:20</TotalProgrammeDuration>
</Timecodes>
<AccessServices>
  <SigningPresent>No</SigningPresent>
  <OpenCaptionsPresent>
  </OpenCaptionsPresent>
</AccessServices>
<AdditionalNode>
  <TextlessElementsExist>True</TextlessElementsExist>
  <CompletionDate>11/02/2016 17:47:42</CompletionDate>
  <ProgrammeHasText>eng</ProgrammeHasText>
</AdditionalNode>
<ContactInformation>
  <ContactEmail>mikemcg@waddellmedia.com</ContactEmail>
</ContactInformation>
</Technical>
</Programme>
```

The second being shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Programme xmlns="http://www.digitalproductionpartnership.co.uk/ns/as11/2015"><Editorial><SeriesTitle>ART</SeriesTitle><ProgrammeTitle>Ep26 Col safe test</ProgrammeTitle><EpisodeTitleNumber>Ep26</EpisodeTitleNumber><ProductionNumber>FKRD991W/01</ProductionNumber><Synopsis>James and Charlie</Synopsis><Originator>STV Productions</Originator><CopyrightYear>2016</CopyrightYear></Editorial><Technical><ShimName>UK DPP HD</ShimName><ShimVersion>1.1</ShimVersion><Video><VideoBitRate unit="Mbps">100</VideoBitRate><VideoCodec>AVC-Intra 100</VideoCodec><VideoCodecParameters>High 4:2:2 Intra@L4.1</VideoCodecParameters><PictureFormat>1080i50 16:9</PictureFormat><AFD>10</AFD><PictureRatio>16:9 (1.78:1)</PictureRatio><ThreeD>false</ThreeD><ProductPlacement>false</ProductPlacement><PSEPass>Yes</PSEPass><PSEManufacturer>Ofcom</PSEManufacturer><PSEVersion>2009</PSEVersion></Video><Audio><AudioSamplingFrequency unit="kHz">48</AudioSamplingFrequency><AudioBitDepth>24</AudioBitDepth><AudioCodecParameters>PCM</AudioCodecParameters><AudioTrackLayout>EBU R 48: 2a</AudioTrackLayout><PrimaryAudioLanguage>eng</PrimaryAudioLanguage><SecondaryAudioLanguage>zxx</SecondaryAudioLanguage><TertiaryAudioLanguage>zxx</TertiaryAudioLanguage><AudioLoudnessStandard>EBU R 128</AudioLoudnessStandard></Audio><Timecodes><LineUpStart>09:59:30:00</LineUpStart><IdentClockStart>09:59:50:00</IdentClockStart><Parts><Part><PartNumber>1</PartNumber><PartTotal>1</PartTotal><PartSOM>10:00:00:00</PartSOM><PartDuration>00:05:25:10</PartDuration></Part></Parts><TotalNumberOfParts>2</TotalNumberOfParts><TotalProgrammeDuration>00:05:25:10</TotalProgrammeDuration></Timecodes><AccessServices><AudioDescriptionPresent>false</AudioDescriptionPresent><ClosedCaptionsPresent>false</ClosedCaptionsPresent><OpenCaptionsPresent>false</OpenCaptionsPresent><SigningPresent>No</SigningPresent></AccessServices><Additional><CompletionDate>2016-01-11</CompletionDate><TextlessElementsExist>false</TextlessElementsExist><ProgrammeHasText>true</ProgrammeHasText><ProgrammeTextLanguage>eng</ProgrammeTextLanguage><AssociatedMediaFilename>Ep26 Col safe test.mxf</AssociatedMediaFilename><MediaChecksumType>MD5</MediaChecksumType><MediaChecksumValue></MediaChecksumValue></Additional><ContactInformation><ContactEmail>lucy.austin@stv.tv</ContactEmail><ContactTelephoneNumber>01413003000</ContactTelephoneNumber></ContactInformation></Technical></Programme>
```

I am trying to extract the total number of parts, but want a single XSL that will work for both. I have managed to get one that works for each individually shown below, but it appears their XPATH is different for both, where one requires its prefix all through the XPATH and the other doesn't. Obviously the other issue is that both their Namespaces are slightly different, is there a way to account for that too?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="//edx:Programme" xmlns:edx="http://www.digitalproductionpartnership.co.uk/ns/as11/2012"><xsl:value-of select="/edx:Programme/Technical/Timecodes/TotalNumberOfParts" /></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The second XSL is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="//edx:Programme" xmlns:edx="http://www.digitalproductionpartnership.co.uk/ns/as11/2015"><xsl:value-of select="/edx:Programme/edx:Technical/edx:Timecodes/edx:TotalNumberOfParts" /></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, Just to clarify is there a way of writing a single XSL to extract the number of parts from both XML's so no matter which XML was the source the transform would work on both?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put both templates as written (with local namespace declarations on the `xsl:template`) into a single stylesheet then the XSLT processor will apply the template matching the input format.

Answer (score 0):

Often when you need to process two different XML vocabularies that are very similar (especially if the namespaces are different), the cleanest way of doing it is to write a transformation that converts one vocabulary into the other (or convert both of them into some common format), rather than trying to handle both varieties in the same process. The benefit is that once you've written your transformation code, it's highly re-usable, and you never have to cope with the two different flavours again.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your XPath match more generically on the structure and `local-name()` of the elements, regardless of which namespaces the elements are bound to.

**XSLT 2.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="*:Programme">
    <xsl:value-of select="*:Technical/*:Timecodes/*:TotalNumberOfParts" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 1.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Programme']">
    <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='Technical']/*[local-name()='Timecodes']/
                              *[local-name()='TotalNumberOfParts']" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```